# Contacts Displaying in App using Reactnative

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to create an App where I can load all my contacts of the phone into my app. So I can see in a list view the name and contact details of each person. How to perform it in expo please guide me as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use below package for getting all contact from your devices!

[react-native-contacts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-contacts)

i've used above package on one of my app there is i've been used getting all contacts

follow this tutorial step by step

hope this will help you :)